# I want to remove a load bearing wall and turn it into an opening with header. Can I stack the load on top of another header's load?

Tags: framing

If this sounds odd, I apologize. I am renovating my kitchen and would like to avoid a big ol' support post right in the middle of the kitchen that will transfer the load down. If it is required, I will suck it up and do it. But I'd like to avoid it if I can.

I am attempting to change a standard load bearing stud wall into an opening with a header. The question I have is this:  Can I transfer the load (ON ONE SIDE OF THE HEADER) to another header that is already bearing a load? Assume in your answer that the existing header is sufficient to carry the load, because I can always increase the size of the existing header if it isn't.

I have attached a picture describing what I'd like. Its the best I could do.

[image]

Comment: ADDITIONAL INFORMATION: DUE TO THE STRUCTURE AND LAYOUT OF THE HOME .... YES, BOTH OF THESE WALLS ARE LOAD BEARING.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can.

The problem is you need a structural engineer to design it and maybe a designer to make it look purrty.

Answer (score 1):

Yes but you might need to double up your existing header.  The existing header would  then be carrying 1/2 the load from the other header at this point.

If you are creating point loads under the header/beam posts you'll need to have sufficient bearing in your slab or in the floor below to carry the loads down to a footing.

I would recommend getting a structural engineer in.  Should be less than $1000 for a site visit and a drawing if you get an owner operator.

Answer (score 0):

Only if the other header, and it's supports, can handle the additional load.

Get a structural engineer to evaluate it it will, and what can be done if not.

This is not something you want to guess at.